# Boost error in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I am new to boost library. I just dragged and drop the boost folder to xCode and entered the header search path. When i compile it is giving error

```
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_HEADER_ONLY)
# error Do not compile Asio library source with BOOST_ASIO_HEADER_ONLY defined
#endif
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just drop the Boost source into Xcode and build it. Use the [build instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) from the Boost documentation.

Comment: Huh, now it does for me too. So prolly my internetz, sorry.